# Fnd nearest comment button, prepend username to the nearest comment text, display none for a image

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, textarea

When the user write a comment (i.e. it's cold today) in the text area and click on comment button, I would like to hide the comment button, disable textarea, and prepend user name (i.e. Mary) before the words inside the disabled textarea (i.e. Mary: it's cold today).

I tried using angular-js but it hides all the comment button. Is there a way that I can find the nearest comment button and only hide that button.  I also tried to prepend the username: Mary but because I am using multiple different ng-repeat element and another '.status' for the post status for the same class name ('.status'), so I am unable to get the $('.status.val()). Is there a way that I can find the nearest comment value to the comment button which the user has clicked.

```
<textarea class='status' name="userStatus" ng-model="status" placeholder="What's on your mind?"> </textarea>  

<div ng-repeat='status in books|orderBy:order' style="background-color:white;padding:20px 20px;margin:15px;" >   
  <textarea  style="margin:15px 0px;" class='status' ng-disabled="isDisabled" rows="1" ng-model="comment" placeholder="Write a comment.."></textarea>                
  <button class="btn btn-info btn-xs" style="margin-left:15px;width:70px" ng-style="disableCommentButton" ng-click="disableClick(this)" >Comment</button> 
</div>
```

When a user post a status and does not upload a picture, is there a way that I can display none for that particular post image:-

```
<textarea class='status' name="userStatus" ng-model="status" placeholder="What's on your mind?"> </textarea>  
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"style="margin-left:10px;width:60px" ng-click="submit()">Post</button>

<div ng-repeat='status in books|orderBy:order' style="background-color:white;padding:20px 20px;margin:15px;" >   
  <img ng-src={{status.url}} style="margin-bottom:15px" class="thumbnail-image" >
</div>
```

The complete source code is:

```
<section id="App2" ng-app="form-input" ng-controller="ctrl">
   <form id="welcome"  >  
      <h4>Update status</h4>
      <hr style="margin-top:-3px">  
      <img class='profilePic'>
      <textarea class='status' name="userStatus" ng-model="status" placeholder="What's on your mind?"> </textarea>  
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"style="margin-left:10px;width:60px" ng-click="submit()">Post</button>
    </form> 
    <summary class="row book-component">    
  <div ng-repeat='status in books|orderBy:order' style="background-color:white;padding:20px 20px;margin:15px;" >   
   <h4 ng-bind="status.author" style="margin-top:2px"></h4>    
   <h4 ng-bind="status.message" style="margin:20px 0px " class="title"></h4> 
   <img ng-src={{status.url}} style="margin-bottom:15px" class="thumbnail-image"   
   <h5 style="margin-top:25px;color:grey;" ng-show="status.counter>0">{{status.counter}} people likes this</h5>
    <h3 class="empty-star" style="margin-top:25px;color:lightblue;display:none;"> 
    <span onclick="rating(1, this)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
    <span onclick="rating(2, this)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
     <span onclick="rating(3, this)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
      <span onclick="rating(4, this)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
      <span onclick="rating(5, this)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
   </h3> 
   <span class="row">
      <img style="margin:15px 15px 0px 0px;" class='profilePic'>
      <textarea  style="margin:15px 0px;" class='status' ng-disabled="isDisabled" rows="1" ng-model="comment" placeholder="Write a comment.."></textarea> 
      <button class="btn btn-info btn-xs" style="margin-left:15px;width:70px" ng-style="disableCommentButton" ng-click="disableClick(this)" >Comment</button> 
   </span> 
  </div> 
  </summary>       

  var app2 = angular.module('form-input', []);
  app2.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {  
  $scope.isDisabled = false;
  $scope.disableClick = function(that) {  
    $scope.isDisabled = true; 
    $scope.disableCommentButton = {'visibility': 'hidden'};
    var tweet = $('.status').val(); 
    $('.status').val("Mary "+ tweet);  
  }
  $scope.submit = function(){   
        $scope.books.unshift(
          { 
            message: $scope.status,  
            author:'Mary' 
          } 
        )  
  }
  /*  Create JSON representations of the content */
  $scope.books=[
    {message:'There is a concert at ...' , url:"http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/3d561d41394ff0d5d0715b2695c3dcf0?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG",author:'Verena Wong'},
    {message:'Jan is 2 years old today.',url:"http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/3d561d41394ff0d5d0715b2695c3dcf0?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG",author:'John Rupert'}
  ];       
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tangjeen/2zj9k872/28/

Comment: Do you want to find the matching comment within an iteration of a `ng-repeat`? Finding `nearest` elements and using css selectors really isn't the angular way; you should avoid any DOM manipulation outside of a directive.

Comment: Yes I would like to find the nearest comment input next to the  comment button where user have clicked on. Is there a way that I can do it, either angular or javascript?

Answer (score 1):

I would forget the term `nearest` as this thinking will lead to using direct DOM manipulation.  Use properties on the angular objects within the `ng-repeat` to disabled/show/hide/etc. your elements.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat='status in books | orderBy:order>   
    <textarea rows="1" ng-disabled="status.isDisabled" ng-model="status.comment"></textarea>
    <button class="btn btn-info btn-xs" ng-click="disableClick(status)">Comment</button> 
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.disableClick = function(book) {  
    book.comment = 'Mary' + book.comment;
    book.isDisabled = true;
}
```